# How to write an ES6 class React Component that extends a function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know in vanilla ES6 you can write a `class` that `extend`s a `function` class. This is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends).

React supports both ES6 class components, via `extend`ing `React.Component`, and function components. I'm getting the following error when attempting to `extend` a function component, though.

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

I'm trying to write some code that extends a component *and* works for both ES6 class components and function components. I want to write a function that returns a component, but instead of a higher order component I just want to extend and modify some props.

Below is some example code that I've tried and does not work. Is this possible? I realize the `BarExtended` would not render `Bar` at all, but I was just testing. Unless this is part of the issue.

```
function Bar() {
    return (
    <h1>Bar</h1>
  );
}

class BarExtended extends Bar {
    render() {
    return (
        <h1>BarExtended</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
    <BarExtended />
    </div>,
  document.getElementById("foo")
);
```

Comment: React recommends composition over inheritance. Functions can be composed easily so if you ditch the inheritance, your problem goes away.

Comment: Actually not just React. The general advice for **modern** OO is that composition is better than inheritance. I consider **extends** to be a code smell for almost all cases except polymorphism. Even then I'd prefer to do polymorphism via interfaces instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Warning this isn't really possible at least to my knowledge to do in terms of react though because you need to inherit from React.Component to make it a react component like so bar is just a function.

```
class Bar extends React.Component {

}
```

You don't have to use classes with react you can use regular functions. But I think what you are looking for is Higher Order Components. Which can give you extra functionality to any components that you pass to it.

```
function Bar(WrappedComponent){
 return class BarExtended extends React.Component {
  addThisFunction(){
    console.log('I extended the wrapped component with functionality')
  }
  render (
    return (
     <WrappedComponent addThisFunction={this.addThisFunction}/>
    )
  )
 }
}
```

You can do this if you really want from regular classes though.
This is right from the classes documentation.

```
function Animal (name) {
  this.name = name;  
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
  console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' barks.');
  }
}

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Could you add an example on how to use the Bar functional component? how would you pass the WrappedComponent, as a prop?

Answer (score 1):

Um.. I think it doesn't make sense at all.

A functional component is just a function, you know, **a render function**.
So extending a functional component means you will override the render function, and.. it means that you override the entire functional component (because it's just a render function), then you extend *nothing*.

Comment: Technically it isn't overridden by the render function, when extended. It acts like a constructor, so if his `Bar` function looked like this `function Bar() { console.log("Hello"); }`, it would output 'Hello', to the console, as soon as an instance of `BarExtended` would be created. So it does extend something, it just doesn't work as a react component since it doesn't extend `React.Component`.

Comment: It actually makes sense because in some cases you want to have two different files for same component. One for react and second one for react-native. You extend both of them by a base component having all the logic. Thus in such case you might have a functional component for render but class component for logic.